# finding if date belong to date range in loop php [edited]

Tags: php, mysql

```
id          id_emp   id_pola  start            end  
------  ----------  -------  -------------  -----------------
    12        5646       28    2021-07-01     2021-07-06       
    13        5646       29    2021-07-07     2021-07-12       
    14        5646       30    2021-07-13     2021-07-18       
    15        5646       28    2021-07-21     2021-07-26       
    16        5646       29    2021-07-27     2021-07-02
```

i have databse like so, and i want to find if certain date belong to one of the data
so far i have function

```
public static function istrue($date) {
$shifter = query data;
    if ($shifter) {
            $date = new DateTime ($date);
    
                    foreach ($shifter as $k => $v) {
                    $start = new DateTime ($v->start);
                    $end = new DateTime ($v->end);
                    if (($date >= $start) && ($date <= $end)){
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                }
}
```

for date 2021-07-01 to 2021-07-06 it return true,but why for bigger date like 2021-07-07 or 2021-07-21 always returnn false? where my missing code. why it not loop?
if there any sugestion or better code.
thanks in advance

edited
the case i try to loop date from 1 to xxx
and try find xxx date exist in it.
scedhule shift

Comment: _why it not loop?..._ Because you break the loop. I think you don't want to return false within the loop

Comment: You've tagged this with [tag:mysql], so why are you ding this at all? Use a query: `SELECT count(*) from myTable where :date between start and end`

Comment: @B001ᛦ i have try with return "yes", i not work either.

Comment: _...i have try with return "yes",..._ No matter what you return but **only** return when you have to stop the loop. You need to return in one case only! `if (($date >= $start) && ($date <= $end)){ return ....`

Comment: ic ic, ill try tonite thanks mate

Comment: solve,  it can not use return "bla", use $return = "bla" instead,  btw thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function istrue($date) {
$shifter = query data;
    if ($shifter) {
            $date = new DateTime ($date);
    
                    foreach ($shifter as $k => $v) {
                    $start = new DateTime ($v->start);
                    $end = new DateTime ($v->end);
                    if (($date >= $start) && ($date <= $end)){
                            $return = "true";
                        } 
                }
return $return;
}
```

solve with modify script like so, thanks dude, even i still confused, why `return true`  always return true never false